# WordPress and Node.js app on the same domain

Tags: node.js, wordpress, cpanel

I have a Node.Js app which runs fine once configured and started via `cPanel`. The root of the app is the '/' path, which is my domain name.

I also have a WordPress installation from where I fetch blog posts to my Node.Js app. The WordPress installation is in `/public_html` in `cPanel`.

Before I start the Node.Js app, the WordPress dashboard is accessible via `domain.com/wp-installation/wp-admin`. After I start my Node.Js app, the app takes over the domain and if I try to again access the WordPress dashboard, I get a 404 error.

Is there a way that I can run them both, at the same time, so that my WordPress dashboard is accessible at all times?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, the trick was to simply go to a specific .php file, example:

https://example.com/wp-migration/wp-admin/edit.php

This opens up the WordPress dashboard and is exactly what I need.